# Get all keys from Chrome Storage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I can get the value of a storage key with the Chrome Extension API:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get("someKey", function() {});
```

How can I get all key names that exist in the Chrome storage?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#StorageArea-methods) (emphasis mine):

> An empty list or object will return an empty result object. **Pass in `null` to get the entire contents of storage.** Don't forget to change "storage.sync" to storage.local if you're using local storage.

For some example code:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items) {
    var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
    console.log(allKeys);
});
```

Comment: Warning: `chrome.storage` does NOT adhere to ES6/ES2015 spec like Chrome -- it will sort your object keys if you store the object through this interface (unlike recent versions of Chrome, which preserves the order of the keys). I have reported this [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/frmBSQcIzcs/YaQ1hLSLAgAJ).